# How to use Keycloak JWT for authentication in Micronaut GraphQL

Tags: graphql, jwt, keycloak, micronaut

I'm trying to use Micronaut GraphQL using keycloak JWT. I was able to get things working with Basic Auth, trying to move over to bearer token instead, and I'm missing something, as I always get a 401 Unauthorized, but I'm not seeing any useful error messages in the log, even with the logging set to TRACE

Using Micronaut 3.0.0.

My application.yml looks like this:

```yaml
micronaut:
  application:
    name: myapp
  server:
    cors:
      enabled: true
    port: 8080
  security:
    authentication: bearer
    intercept-url-map:
      - pattern: /graphiql
        access:
          - isAnonymous()
      - pattern: /graphql
        access:
          - isAuthenticated()
    endpoints:
      login:
        enabled: false
    token:
      jwt:
        enabled: true
        signatures:
          jwks:
            keycloak:
              url: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8090/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
    oauth2.clients.keycloak:
      grant-type: password
      client-id: myapp-backend
      client-secret: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
      authorization:
        url:  http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8090/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth
custom:
  keycloak:
    url: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8090

graphql:
  enabled: true
  path: /graphql
  graphiql:
    enabled: true
    path: /graphiql
```

here is what I'm posting to test:

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8080/graphql' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {exceptionally long jwt token}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"query":"query test { scenarios { id } }","operationName":"test"}'
```

I'm not sure what else would be useful to provide. Any thoughts?

Comment: What does you request look like?

Comment: added added my test curl statement (with jwt token removed)

Comment: I don't know much about micronaut but shouldn't there be an openid configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more searching and stepping through in the debugger, I was able to finally determine that I had mistyped my realm name.

However, for posterity, here is the minimal configuration that I needed to run:

```yaml
micronaut:
  application:
    name: myapplication
  server:
    cors:
      enabled: true
    port: 8080
  security:
    enabled: true
    authentication: bearer
    intercept-url-map:
      - pattern: /graphiql
        access:
          - isAnonymous()
      - pattern: /graphql
        access:
          - isAuthenticated()
    endpoints:
      login:
        enabled: false
    token:
      jwt:
        enabled: true
        signatures:
          jwks:
            keycloak:
              url: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8090/auth/realms/MyRealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
    oauth2.clients.keycloak:
      grant-type: password
      client-id: myapp-backend
      client-secret: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
      authorization:
        url: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8090/auth/realms/MyRealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth

custom:
  keycloak:
    url: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8090/auth/realms/MyRealm

graphql:
  enabled: true
  graphiql.enabled: true
  graphql-ws.enabled: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Micronaut but isn't this missing an openid configuration like this:

```yaml
micronaut:
  security:
    oauth2.clients.keycloak.openid:
      issuer: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8090/auth/realms/myrealm
```

Comment: no, that didn't correct my error, however, my issue was I messed up my realm name. I'll post an answer with the minimum necessary configuration for posterity.

Comment: to be clear, this was helpful, because I didn't have my url fully specified in the `custom.keycloak.url` section.